# Window Toast notification with WPF .Net Framework 4.8 is empty on show

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, toast, .net-4.8

I installed the Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications NuGet package as by this instructions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=desktop

Now I made a test Toast and tried to show it by this way:

```
    public Toast()
    {
        ToastContentBuilder test = new ToastContentBuilder();
        test.AddHeader(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),"my first notification!", "HeaderArgument");
        test.SetToastScenario(ToastScenario.Reminder);
        test.AddArgument("myKey", "myValue");
        test.AddText("This is a cool Toast!");
        test.AddInlineImage(new Uri("https://picsum.photos/360/202?image=883"));
        test.AddAppLogoOverride(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/Andrew.jpg"), ToastGenericAppLogoCrop.Circle);

        test.Show(toast =>
        {
            toast.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
            toast.Group = "myApp";
        });
    }
```

But when it shows up the header is Dev-Debug with the message (roughly translated) "New notification!"
When I click it, my app is activated, but the argument is empty.
I registered the toast like this:

```
ToastNotificationManagerCompat.OnActivated += toastArgs =>
{
    ToastArguments args = ToastArguments.Parse(toastArgs.Argument);
    ValueSet userInput = toastArgs.UserInput;
    Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Toast activated. Args: " + toastArgs.Argument);
        ToastNotificationManagerCompat.History.RemoveGroup("myApp");
    });
};
```

The last part with removing the history group works fine... so the toast.Group is working, but the rest before isn't... someone an idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> someone an idea how to make this work?

Try to remove the call to `AddAppLogoOverride` or specify an absolute path to the logo image, e.g.:

```
test.AddAppLogoOverride(new Uri("C:\\...\\Andrew.png"), ToastGenericAppLogoCrop.Circle);
```

`ms-appdata` is not supported in an unpackaged WPF app.

Comment: Thanks. Now the arguments are transferred. The other one, the `AddInlineImage` didn't work either. It is not shown. To my luck I only need to show a toast with a text message...